# How to deal with different JSON HTTP response in swift

Tags: json, swift, http, struct

For Example,

I have a list of categories in (Food, Entertainment, Travel) a TableView Format.

The next view should show a list of items in a TableView format based on the selected category from the previous view controller but each category list has a different set of JSON object in response.

What would the best approach?

Can I create an array of struct variables, then pull an appropriate struct variable dynamically from the array inside JSON Decoder like JSONDecoder().decode(structArray[0].self, data: data!) like that?

I really want to avoid long tail if statements...

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: `JSONDecoder` is the more static the more convenient and vice versa. And at some point there is a threshold where the advantage over manual `JSONSerialization` is <= 0

Answer (score 0):

I assume you make a API call when category is selected.

You can use ObjectMapper library to map JSON to appropiate Model Object you want. And can use interface with the Model Object to call the primitives.

You can also use Alamofire library with AlamofireObjectMapper to make your api(JSON) call which can directly return you a mapped Object.

There is a StaticMappable protocol in object mapper which usses object for mapping. So you can also map a collection(object) inside your json(object) to your own custom map class.